# How to mock a module in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock one of my action creator in Jest. Actually, I'm testing my React component. And I need to check if the action-creator function was called on some event. I tried to mock the the function through `jest.mock`, but throws error saying:

```
Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of Jest test environment.
```

Here is what I've tried so far, but it's not working:

```js
describe('>> SCREEN -- Tests Step1', () => {
  describe('• handleSubmit function tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.mock('../../redux/modules/test/test', () => ({
        fetchUser : jest.fn()
      }))
    })

    it('Should call fetchUser when called', () => {
      handleSubmit({ value : '1234' })

      expect(fetchUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
})
```

I've also tried to mock the function outside of the test suits. but that also didn't work. I'm not sure what am I missing here.

Please let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: How are you importing and using fetchUser in your code?

Comment: it's a partial import. I'm importing it like:
`import {fetchUser} from '../../....`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can approach it.

```
import * as api from "../../redux/modules/test/test";

test("...", () => {
    const userSpy = jest.spyOn(api, 'fetchUser');

    handleSubmit({ value : '1234' });

    expect(userSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Ah, this would work in this case. But now the problem is I want to mock `react-redux`'s `useSelector` and I want it to return a mock value. Any idea how to do that..

Comment: First you need to wrap your component inside Redux Provider. After dispatch some action which makes a selector update... I think you need to update code sample or make a new question.